# Lombok installed but still getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'Slf4j'`

Tags: java, intellij-idea, slf4j, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Trying to run a test but the build stops at `java: package lombok.extern.slf4j does not exist`.

Tried reinstalling Lombok plugin, enable annotation processing has been ticked, and I have tried reinstalling Intellij IDEA community edition.
Any other fixes?

Comment: Please try doing invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try building the project from terminal to eliminate any dependency related issues.

Comment: Are you using a build tool? If so, can you show the configuration of that (e.g. `pom.xml`)? If not, what are your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild stab here, but lombok doesn't *include* `slf4j`. It really can't do that1. All features in the `extern` packages work like this, and it is why the `lombok.extern` package layer exists: To show you that it's a lombok feature that makes some non-core ('external') dependency work nicer, not that the lombok feature includes this dependency or replaces it.

Thus, all you would need to fix this is to add slf4j to your dependencies:

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j:1.7.31'
```

omr something along those lines. Note that SLF4j also needs runtime configuration (slf4j itself is just a 'frontend' that lets you write log statements that go to whereever your configuration says they go at runtime. This 'configuration' includes the code to actually do stuff with these logs. Slf4j tutorials will cover all this.

[1] Adding the deps automatically is not really possible; lombok ships with a number of features that are specifically to make some library / framework easier to use, we (DISCLAIMER: I do quite a bit of work on lombok) can't ship them **all of those** as deps of lombok, and we haven't (and probably would never) try to hack into your build system to make some sort of semi-dependent system where we detect you use e.g. `@Slf4j` and somehow make your build system include it only then.

Comment: I think that would lead to a different error (e.g. `java: package org.slf4j.api does not exist` as opposed to `java: package lombok.extern.slf4j does not exist`